# React Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property [property_name] of undefined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm passing a property from Parent component `<CampersList _data={this.state.data}/>`, help me to understand, how should I get property `_data[0].updated.$t`. 
Currently it returns me an error:
[image]
Here's the code of the child component:

```
class CampersList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    let campersNodes = this.props._data.map((element, index) => {
        return (
            <Camper user={element} index={index} key={index}/>

        );
    });
    let updateDate = this.props._data[0].updated.$t;
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                {campersNodes}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>{updateDate}</p>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But if I would reduce `let updateDate = this.props._data[0].updated.$t;` to
`let updateDate = this.props._data[0];` then it throws me different error:
[image]

Comment: Check what `this.props._data` is.

Comment: @dfsq this.props._data is an Array of objects

Comment: can u show some sample data for  _data ??

Comment: Chances are your '_data' is at some point empty, and thus accessing the element at index 0 results in `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that data[0] is undefined.

In simple words, react takes a few milliseconds to update its props till then they are undefined. So initially `data[0] is undefined`.

**Solution 1: To solve this try putting them inside an `if` condition.**

```
if(this.props._data[0]) {
  //code
}
```

**Solution 2: Use [getDefaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-prop-types-and-default-props), which gives default props. This solution is recommended by react**

```
getDefaultProps() {
  return {
     _data: []
  };
}
```

Comment: I've added some more information to my question, maybe it would clearify the question

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv I am getting confused with what you want to achieve with `this.props._data[0].updated.$t`. Do u want to access updated array or it has some property with name updated? And what is this `$t` because as far as I know, react donot have something like $ to access variables/arrays/objects

Comment: No it is not possible for as long as u pass correct props to the component. Most probably the problem is with the `$`. I am not able to get what `$` is doing in reactjs

Comment: It would be helpful if u can post a screenshot of the returned JSON or the complete format of _data

Answer (score 1):

We usually face this kind of issues in react. The reason is when the render method is executed the data might not be available to you, which you must be fetching through some network calls.
You can use some conditional statements like:

`let updateDate = this.props._data[0] ? this.props._data[0].updated.$t : null;`
which will again run into trouble if `this.props._data[0].updated` is undefined.

So you will have to nest again to check if the variable is defined or not.

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#get) gives you some cool methods like `get` to handle this situations.
simply use:

`let updateDate = _.get(this.props, '_data[0].updated.$t', 'Default Value');`

Comment: I've added some more information to my question, maybe it would clearify the question

Comment: Since `updateDate ` is an javascript object you cannot directly render whole object inside render method.